# Rails fields for with collection_check_boxes

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, forms

I have three models, segment being the one which has many segment_timezones and segment_locales.

Segment.rb

```
class Segment < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :core_bot
  has_many :segment_timezones, dependent: :destroy
  has_many :segment_locales, dependent: :destroy
  has_many :segments_to_subscribers, dependent: :destroy

  accepts_nested_attributes_for :segment_locales, allow_destroy: true
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :segment_timezones, allow_destroy: true
end
```

Segment_timezone.rb

```
class SegmentTimezone < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :segment
end
```

Segment_locale.rb

```
class SegmentLocale < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :segment
end
```

I created a form with fields_for in order to save multiple timezones and locales filters for my segments:

```
<%= form_for(segment) do |f| %>
...
<%= f.fields_for :segment_timezones do |r| %>
    <div class="fields">
      <label>Filter by Timezone</label><br>
      <%= r.collection_check_boxes :timezone, @bot_users, :timezone, :id, { :multiple => true } do |b| %>
        <%= b.check_box(:type => "check_box") %>
        <%= "UTC "+b.value.to_s %>
        <%= ActiveSupport::TimeZone[b.value.to_f].name %>
      <% end %>
    </div>
  <% end %>

  <%= f.fields_for :segment_locales do |r| %>
    <div class="fields">
      <label>Filter by Spoken Languages</label><br>
      <%= r.collection_check_boxes :locale, @bot_users, :locale, :id, { :multiple => true } do |l| %>
      <%= l.check_box(:type => "check_box") %>
      <%= l.value.to_s %>
      <% end %>
    </div>
  <% end %>

<% end %>
```

What I would like to achieve is to save the main segment and in the same time save an entry for each checkbox in the tables segment_timezone and segment_locale. This would allow me to save the filters the user wants to apply to his segment.

Unfortunately with this configuration only the main segment is saved but no segment_timezone or segment_locale.

Here is my segment controller:

```
def new
    @segment = Segment.new
    @segment.segment_timezones.build
    @segment.segment_locales.build

    @user = current_user
    @bot = CoreBot.find_by_user_id(@user.id)
    @bot_users = BotUser.where(core_bot_id: @bot.id)
  end

def create
    @user = current_user
    @bot = CoreBot.find_by_user_id(@user.id)
    @bot_users = BotUser.where(core_bot_id: @bot.id)

    @segment = Segment.new(segment_params)

    respond_to do |format|
      if @segment.save
        format.html { redirect_to @segment, notice: 'Segment was successfully created.' }
        format.json { render :show, status: :created, location: @segment }
      else
        format.html { render :new }
        format.json { render json: @segment.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end

def segment_params
      params.require(:segment).permit(:core_bot_id, :name, :gender, :creation_date_start, :creation_date_finish, segment_timezones_attributes: [ :id, :segment_id, :timezone ], segment_locales_attributes: [ :id, :segment_id, :locale ])
    end
```

For now, I get the following error:

> 2 errors prohibited this segment from being saved: 
>   segment timezones segment must exist 
>   Segment locales segment must exist

Thank you for your help.

Comment: Where is the `create` (or `update`) action in your controller? This is the critical one, since you are performing a `POST` request.

Comment: I added the create action in the question.

Comment: can u show what request you are getting in server from client when form submitted

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Try this**

Segment_timezone.rb

```
class SegmentTimezone < ApplicationRecord
  serialize :timezone
  belongs_to :segment, optional: true
end
```

Segment_locale.rb

```
class SegmentLocale < ApplicationRecord
  serialize :locale
  belongs_to :segment, optional: true
end
```

Comment: It works but I get this error: Unpermitted parameter: timezone
; Unpermitted parameter: locale. However, "timezone" and "locale" are in my list of permited parameters... Any idea?

Comment: Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"0CeImV8DOd5YcgmX50U3KeWjWZqaOx3891xeL37ySUJtapN94Np9cJVpmyNU4SkoSkx+qZvP5/CDvqKZFhx8RA==", "segment"=>{"name"=>"ploup", "gender"=>"All", "creation_date_start"=>"", "creation_date_finish"=>"", "segment_timezones_attributes"=>{"0"=>{"timezone"=>["", "5.5"]}, "1"=>{"timezone"=>["", "5.5"]}}, "segment_locales_attributes"=>{"0"=>{"locale"=>["", "fr_FR"]}, "1"=>{"locale"=>["", "fr_FR"]}}, "core_bot_id"=>"1"}, "commit"=>"Create Segment"}

Comment: By the way, I duplicated the input intentionally to see if it works with multiple checkboxes.

Comment: timezone and locale are array, so try permit as following.

params.require(:segment).permit(:core_bot_id, :name, :gender, :creation_date_start, :creation_date_finish, segment_timezones_attributes: [ :id, :segment_id, :timezone=>[]], segment_locales_attributes: [ :id, :segment_id, :locale=>[] ]) end

Comment: Thanks, there is no more errors but it does not save the "timezone" and "locale" values, example: INSERT INTO "segment_timezones" ("segment_id", "created_at", "updated_at") VALUES (?, ?, ?)  [["segment_id", 17], ["created_at", "2017-09-19 04:55:53.714263"], ["updated_at", "2017-09-19 04:55:53.714263"]]

Comment: Try to serialize the field in model like this.  
serialize :timezone

Comment: Thanks, it works now, but timezone and locale don't get the right value, only "0": INSERT INTO "segment_locales" ("segment_id", "locale", "created_at", "updated_at") VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?)  [["segment_id", 19], ["locale", 0], ["created_at", "2017-09-19 05:01:30.758026"], ["updated_at", "2017-09-19 05:01:30.758026"]]

Comment: Which db ur using

Comment: I'm using Postgre

Comment: remove old column and 

add_column :table_name, :column_name, :string, array: true, default: []

Comment: Please upvote and accept my answer if you found it's useful

Comment: Now it works but I get a weird array in my db, is it possible to just get the value I want instead of a array? INSERT INTO "segment_locales" ("segment_id", "locale", "created_at", "updated_at") VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?)  [["segment_id", 2], ["locale", "---\n- ''\n- fr_FR\n"], ["created_at", "2017-09-19 05:39:35.485208"], ["updated_at", "2017-09-19 05:39:35.485208"]]

Comment: It will insert like that but while fetching like obj.column you will see value as array only.Try it

Comment: Yes it works, it's a pity I can't just store the value instead of a array but I will mark this as the answer. Thanks!